# Order of complexity proofs. Show that $n^3-5n+1=O(n^3)$.

Tags: asymptotics

Show that $n^3-5n+1=O(n^3)$.
I did the following:
Using the definition of big-Oh, we need to show that there exist $n_0$  and $C$ such that $n^3-5n+1 \leq Cn^3$  is valid for some constant $C > 0$ and for all $n > n_0$.
First, choose $n_0=1$. Then $1^3-5 \cdot 1+1=C\cdot 1^3$=> $C=-3$. Since by definition of big-Oh, $C$ should be greater than $0$. $C= -3$ should not work. How can I prove this order of complexity?

Comment: Try using $C=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The condition is really
$$\bigl|n^3-5n+1\bigr| \leq Cn^3$$
so you can use the triangle inequality.

*Another approach*:  a polynomial is *asymptotically equivalent* to its leading term, so $n^3-5n+1\sim_\infty n^3$, which is stronger than being $O\bigl(n^3\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some ambiguity with the definition that you are working with, but at least for me I am used to $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if there is $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $C\geq 0$ such that $x\geq x_0$ implies $|f(x)|\leq Cg(x)$ (notice the absolute values). Then in your case, choose $n_0=5$ and $C=1$. We have for $n\geq n_0$

$$0<n(n^2-5)=n^3-5n<n^3-5n+1<n^3$$

Then

$$|n^3-5n+1|\leq 1\cdot n^3$$

implies $n^3-5n+1=O(n^3)$.

Comment: How can I also prove this: If f1 is O(f2) and f2 is O(g), then f1 is O(g).

Comment: $|f_1|\leq C_1 f_2\leq C_1|f_2|\leq C_2 g$

Comment: Take $C_2=C_1 K$ where $|f_2|\leq K g$